# In EF I'm looking for duplicates and doing a self-referencing query, how do I write this query?

Tags: entity-framework

Here is the SQL statement:

```
SELECT f1.*
FROM [File] f1
where 1 < (select count(*) from [File] f2 where f1.FileName = f2.FileName)
order by f1.FileName
```

This is a fairly simple query to do in SQL, but I'm not sure how to do it in EF.  The closest I've come to the answer is this (gives me the PK and count), but I want the full file record back:

```
from f1 in File
join f2 in File on f1.FileName equals f2.FileName      
group f1 by f1.FileId into c
where c.Count() > 1
select new { FileId = c.Key, number = c.Count() }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [group join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx):

```
from f1 in File
join f2 in File on f1.FileName equals f2.FileName into g     
where g.Count() > 1
select f1
```

Comment: Thanks!  This looks like the best fit.  LinqPad says it translates to:
 -- Region Parameters
DECLARE @@p0 Int = 1
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t0].[FileId], [t0].[FileName], [t0].[DirectoryDefaultStructureId], [t0].[ProjectId], [t0].[AssetId], [t0].[BusinessUnitId], [t0].[UploadedOn], [t0].[CreatorUserId]
FROM [File] AS [t0]
WHERE ((
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [File] AS [t1]
    WHERE [t0].[FileName] = [t1].[FileName]
    )) > @@p0

Answer (score 0):

I generally use EF with lambda syntax but couldn't you just project the object?

```
from f1 in File
join f2 in File on f1.FileName equals f2.FileName      
group f1 by f1.FileId into c
where c.Count() > 1
select c
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  This syntax actually crashed my LinqPad when I ran it.  When I looked at the SQL it would generate, it was "interesting" to say the very least.  Ivan's answer above seems to be more of what I'm looking for and the SQL looks better, but I do thank you for your time.